# jQuery "add" Only Evaluated When "appendTo" Called

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, concatenation, addition

this has been driving me crazy since yesterday afternoon. I am trying to concatenate two bodies of selected HTML using jQuery's "add" method. I am obviously missing something fundamental. Here's some sample code that illustrated the problem:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="para1">This is a test.</p>
    <p id="para2">This is also a test.</p>

    <script>
        var para1 = $("#para1").clone();
        var para2 = $("#para2").clone();

        var para3 = para1.add(para2);

        alert("Joined para: " + para3.html());

        para3.appendTo('body');

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I need to do some more manipulation to "para3" before the append, but the alert above displays only the contents of "para1." However, the "appendTo appends the correct, "added" content of para1 and para2 (which subsequently appears on the page).

Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: Read the [`$.add`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) (and `$.html`) documentation. $para3 is a jQuery selector of *two* elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [`$.add`](http://api.jquery.com/add/),

> Create a new jQuery object with elements *added* to the set of matched elements.

Thus, after the `add`, $para3 represents a jQuery result set of *two* elements ~> [$para1, $para2]. Then, per [`$.html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/),

> Get the HTML contents of the *first element* in the set of matched elements or set the HTML contents of every matched element.

So the HTML content of the *first* item in the jQuery result ($para1) is returned and subsequent elements (including $para2) are ignored. This behavior is consistent across jQuery "value reading" functions.

Reading `$.appendTo` will explain how it works differently from `$.html`.

---

A simple map and array-concat can be used to get the HTML of "all items in the result set":

```
$.map($para3, function (e) { return $(e).html() }).join("")

Array.prototype.map.call($para3, function (e) { return $(e).html() }).join("")
```

Or in this case, just:

```
$para1.html() + $para2.html()
```

Another approach would be to get the inner HTML of a parent *Element*, after the children have been added.